# How to connect to db with mongo shell using MONGOLAB_URI?

Tags: mongodb, heroku

On heroku everything what is needed to connect to db is stored in [`MONGOLAB_URI`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/connection-string/) variable. But it is used primary by mongo drivers - not humans.

```
$ heroku config
=== app Config Vars
LANG:                     en_US.UTF-8
MONGOLAB_URI:             mongodb://heroku_app123456:2fsf445D@ds039880.mongolab.com:39880/heroku_app123456
```

Is there some fast method how to connect to db using just mongo shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any option in `man mongo` how to do that.

So one (of many) possible way is this AWK one-liner:

```
gawk '/MONGOLAB_URI/ { print gensub( /mongodb:\/\/([[:print:]]+):([[:print:]]+)@(.*)/, "-u \\1 -p \\2  \\3","g",$2)}'
```

Usage:

```
$ mongo $(heroku config | gawk '/MONGOLAB_URI/ { print gensub( /mongodb:\/\/([[:print:]]+):([[:print:]]+)@(.*)/, "-u \\1 -p \\2  \\3","g",$2)}')
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5
connecting to: ds039880.mongolab.com:39880/heroku_app123456
rs-ds039880:PRIMARY>
```

It doesn't count with replica sets and so on, just simple db setup. For trickier URI's use some driver.

---

Another possible way is to [open](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#connect-string) administration of mongolab addon and there should be **prepared** "connection" string. Can not confirm if there is password/username pair included.

```
$ heroku addons:open mongolab
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there is a way to do this from the mongo shell, but from the terminal you can just run `mongo [mongodb uri]`

Comment: This does not work in `2.6` nor `3.0.5`. But yeah, best answer now :)